# Power Supply Nixie tubes (IN 9)

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, boost, nixie

I am in big trouble with my power supply for Nixie tubes ([IN 9 bargraph](https://www.radiomuseum.org/tubes/tube_in-9.html).)

[image]

I need 140V -160V (150V prefered) output voltage and 10x 12mA --> ~140mA current.  (~ 21W).

1. I tried to design boost converters but I wasn't able to get one with this amount of power. Does anyone have a schematic with such a boost converter?

I prefer THT components but if it is SMD there won't be a problem.

2. I also tried the idea with 2 transformers. One (50VA) 230V to 6VAV and one (50VA) 230VAC to 12VAC (secondary sides wired together). And I added rectifier and capacitors. But if I add a load (to reach 130mA ~ 1k2Ohm) the output voltage goes down from 160VDC to 120VDC.

So does anyone have an idea how to build a power supply with these power speficifications?

The load varies (min 0.5mA to max 130mA.)

Comment: From the Nixie applications I recall, two voltages are used + and -, so the semiconductor switches can be relatively low-voltage transistors.

Comment: What the heck kind (and quantity) of Nixie tubes do you have that require 21W?? Typically they're a couple mA each.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The Rodan CD-47 takes \$25\:\text{mA}\$, for example. N of those can add up.

Comment: @jonk Okay, that's a monster Nixie. Perhaps aptly named.

Comment: Just for completion and nothing more related to this question, the [Rodan CD 47 specs](http://www.tube-tester.com/sites/nixie/data/cd47-gr414.htm) are on a regular web page (not PDF.) The specs are in English but the page is partly "auf Deutsch" (I read German fine.)

Comment: To the OP, have you considered or looked at the MAX1771 IC?

Comment: Ran into a fellow the other day who built a sort of audio spectrograph using IN9 tubes.  It'll be a week before I'll see him again - don't have his number (or even his name.)  I'll ask about it the next time I see him, though.

Comment: You already have a large transformer with a secondary of \$12\:\text{V}_\text{AC}\$. Shelve the other one for a different project. Use an IC to help, such as (but not necessarily) the MAX1771. But everything will matter. Select a FET with low \$R_{\text{DS}_\text{ON}}\$ and low \$Q_\text{g}\$. The diode's maximum reverse recovery time will be critical. (The [Vishay ES2F](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88588/es2f.pdf) is a good option.) Make sure you also pay careful attention to how the gate is hooked up to the IC. The speed at which you switch the FET will directly impact your efficiency.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I already tried something like this but can you recommend me a concrete FET, because I think I have here the big problem. Or better a whole circuit which I can simulate in LTspice.

Comment: An unregulated DC supply will always vary by the amount of ripple from 1.41 x rms from low to max load. A transformer VA must be derated at least 30% when rectified to DC. So an AC-DC regulator seems the best fit. Go shop.

Comment: I can not find any with these power specifications.

Comment: Got a chance to talk to the guy with the IN9 spectrograph.  Turns out he just bought an 80W 12V to 150V booster rather than design and build it himself.  The module is enclosed - not much chance of seeing what's in it without completely disassembling his gadget and the booster module.

Comment: On the helpful side, he mentioned that the IN9 is current controlled.  All of his take less than 18mA each for full height.  Down side is that full height is a **different** current for each IN9.  He has to calibrate each one to be able to drive them evenly.